# Derived set of open set

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a non-empty set. Let $\mathcal{T}$ be a topology on $X$.
If a $A \subseteq X$, $D(A)$ will refer to the derived set of $A$.

Now, let $\Omega$ be an open set in the topology $\mathcal{T}$. Is always true that $\Omega \subseteq D(\Omega)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not always the case. If $\mathcal{T}$ is the discrete topology, then a singleton of $X$ is open, but its derived set is empty.

Comment: Sorry, I meant it the other way around. I just edited my question.

Comment: Ok, then I edited my answer as well.